# with spring security oauth, how to read access token from cookie for validation

Tags: cookies, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring security oauth for authentication purpose. I am currently using the RemoteTokenServices to redirect to check token endpoint and validate the token. And I have configured that in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.
Now I need to change my app to get token from cookie instead of Authorization header. After that the RemoteTokenservice way is not working. Is there any other way that I can validate the access token in the cookie?